# "Dormir" pode eventualmente ser um verbo pronominal?

Tags: gramática, expressões, ditado-popular

Na expressão "durma-se com um barulho desses", o verbo dormir está sendo usado como um verbo pronominal. Embora eu reconheça que a expressão é de uso popular, e que o uso popular muitas vezes consagra, tenho dúvida se é gramaticalmente correto.

A variante "durma com um barulho desses", certamente não deixa dúvida.

Comment: Centaurus, se não te for incômodo, onde viste essa frase ou foi oralmente?

Comment: Ouvi no rádio recentemente, de um comentarista político.  Mas já tinha ouvido muitas vezes antes.

Answer (score 2):

Me parece ser um caso não de pronominalização, mas sim de [sujeito indeterminado](https://www.normaculta.com.br/sujeito-indeterminado/), e que estaria correto gramaticalmente - se poderia reescrever a expressão como, e.g., "Quem consegue dormir com uma dessas?".

Vale mencionar o significado da expressão, [supostamente](https://blogs.correiobraziliense.com.br/azedo/nas-entrelinhas-durma-se-com-esse-barulho/) um provérbio português, que entendo como sendo "Isso é perturbador/confuso/estranho (ao ponto de prejudicar o sono)."